# SQL: Automatically recording time of input

Tags: mysql, sql, time

I have a database that will be tracking something over time, and I want to see how the data changes over time. Periodically, it adds some data to a table.

When data is added, is there some sort of metadata I can grab the time from, or is it a better idea to just add a "time sent" column that is filled out by a script, at the cost of more data being sent?

I'm using MySQL if that makes any difference.

Comment: Welcome to SO. You are expected to do some research on a problem yourself. Googling on 'mysql automatic time' brings this up: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/timestamp-initialization.html

Comment: @Nick I think I read that while looking it up, and it looks like it was just saying to add another column. Granted, it is fairly easy to do, I was just wondering if there was a way to get around it without making a column. Sorry.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

ALTER TABLE `yourschema`.`yourtable` 
ADD COLUMN `date` TIMESTAMP NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP;

Comment: Hey everybody!  Let's all down vote without giving a reason even though a proper answer was given!!!   Yay!!!!!

Comment: So adding a column is the way to go? Thank you.

Comment: don't forget to click the check to accept the answer